# How to take DST into account when calculating the offset between two dates?

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

I need to calculate the number of hours between two given timestamps. This software is being written in a location where it's important to take DST time switches into account.

To test this, I am checking the difference between 2022-03-27 and 2022-03-28. The expected result is 23 hours, but I am having some issues getting there with the code that I wrote:

```
DateTime start = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(2022, 3, 27), DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTime end = start.AddDays(1);

DateTime startutc = start.ToUniversalTime(); // this returns 2022-03-26 23:00:00
DateTime endutc = end.ToUniversalTime(); // this returns 2022-03-27 22:00:00

var diff = (end - start).TotalHours; // This returns 24
var diffutc = (endutc - startutc).TotalHours; // This returns 23
```

When converting dates to UTC, C# accurately takes into account the DST specifications of the local timezone. However, when calculating the number of hours between two dates, it does not.

Is there a way to make this calculation without performing back-and-forth timezone conversions?

Comment: Are your *timestamps* genuinely in local time? Ideally they should be in UTC - aside from anything else, local times can be ambiguous. There are plenty of times *not* to use UTC IMO, but for timestamps I would use UTC consistently if you possibly can.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sadly this logic is needed, as I am building logic for daily aggregations, and "daily" is meant to respect DST. Some days consist of 23 hours, some 25. This is a requirement I am in no position to challenge.

Comment: It sounds like these aren't really timestamps then. (I think of a timestamp as "when something happened".) It seems entirely reasonable to me that you start with a date, consider the instant when it started and ended, and take the difference between them. If you're willing to consider the Noda Time library I maintain, the type system there would help keep the concepts straight... (For example, you'd start with a `LocalDate`, then call `AtStartOfDayInZone(zone)` - which takes into account time zones where sometimes midnight doesn't happen around daylight saving time changes...)

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.op_subtraction?view=net-6.0):

> The `Subtraction(DateTime, DateTime)` method does not consider the value of the `Kind` property of the two `DateTime` values when performing the subtraction. Before subtracting `DateTime` objects, ensure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. Otherwise, the result will include the difference between time zones.
>
> > Note
> >
> > The `DateTimeOffset.Subtraction(DateTimeOffset, DateTimeOffset)` method does consider the difference between time zones when performing the subtraction.

So store your values as `DateTimeOffset` instead

```cs
var start = new DateTimeOffset(2022, 3, 27, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(0));
var end = new DateTimeOffset(2022, 3, 28, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

var diff = (end - start).TotalHours; // This returns 23
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bH2ggw)